# Use type before full declaration

Tags: ada

I have a simple question but I can't find the answer.

Is it possible in Ada to have 2 types containing a component of each other's type?

Here is a simple example of what I want to do:

```
type Toto is record
   T: Titi;
end record;

type Titi is record
   T: Toto;
end record;
```

It is not working in this way but is it possible to make something equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this: how should an instance of Toto ever be created? It has to contain an instance of Titi, which in turn contains a Toto, and so on.

However, something similar is possible:

```
type Titi;

type Toto is record
   T : access Titi;
end record;

type Titi is record
   T : Toto;
end record;
```

In that case, Toto only contains a reference/a pointer to a record of type Titi, not an actual Titi.
In order to find optimal type declarations, think carefully about what you want to represent with these types, and what the relationships really are. I am certain you will find that what you presented in your question does not accurately represent your problem. Instead, at least one of Toto.T and Titi.T needs to be represented by an access value -- possibly both.
You do not say what the problem at hand is, so I do not know what would be the best (most fitting) type declaration here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to forward declare Titi. I think the following should do it:

```
type Titi;

type Toto is record
   T: Titi;
end record;

type Titi is record
   T: Toto;
end record;
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, the compiler say:
invalid use of type before its full declaration

Comment: @Ansgar Esztermann has it right, using a pointer/access. The problem here is that the titi & toto declarations refer to themselves infinitely.

Comment: Yup. If the compiler actually tried to do what he is asking, it would have to keep creating record fields infinitely, like the images in mirrors placed on opposite walls. Given that his machine does not have infinite memory, and he doesn't have eternity to wait, it seems pretty reasonable for a compiler (for any language) to flag this as an error. :-)

Comment: @NWS you are right. I missed the access attribute. Seems it is too long ago that I needed this. :-)